mmap'd data seems to be delayed when accessed in user space
I am currently writing a PCIe driver to handle moving data between an FPGA and an ARM64 based CPU. I have a memory mapped array of void pointers acting as a receive buffer. Each packet that is received from the FPGA will be written to a buffer in that array, when a full packet is in the buffer the user space side is alerted so it can start using the data.
Here is the user space side of the mmap code:
do
        {
            m_bufs[m_numBufs] = mmap(0, PKT_MAX_SIZE,
                                         PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED_VALIDATE | MAP_LOCKED,
                                         fd, 0);

            // if we got an error back from the driver, it has no more buffers to map
            if (m_bufs[m_numBufs] == (void *)-1)
            {
                printf("mmap errno: %d\n", errno);
                perror("mmap");
                done = true;
            }
            else
            {
                m_numBufs++;
            }
     // keep going until the driver runs out of buffers, or we run out of pointers for them
        } while (!done && (m_numBufs < NUM_PKT_BUFS));

and the kernel side of it:
vma->vm_page_prot = pgprot_noncached(vma->vm_page_prot);

            ret = remap_pfn_range(vma, vma->vm_start,
                                  virt_to_phys(lowspeed_dat.rx_pkt_queue.buffers[lowspeed_dat.rx_pkt_queue.mapping_idx]) >> PAGE_SHIFT,
                                  vma->vm_end - vma->vm_start, vma->vm_page_prot);
            if (ret)
            {
                printk("error - remapping pages failed\n");
                ret = -EAGAIN;
            }
            else
            {
                printk("(%d, %d) CHAN A start => 0x%08lx, end => 0x%08lx\n",
                       queue_dat.mapping_mode, lowspeed_dat.rx_pkt_queue.mapping_idx, vma->vm_start, vma->vm_end);
               lowspeed_dat.rx_pkt_queue.mapping_idx++;
            }

I am having an issue where it seems like there is a noticeable amount of latency in when the data is available in user space. Essentially my blocking call is returning to user space signaling data is available, when this happens I am printing the first 32 bits of the data (the header) and writing the entire contents of the packet to a file(for testing purposes). With 0 added delays it roughly 90% of the buffers show as empty, no rhyme or reason as to which ones are not empty. If you go back and reread the buffer after a second or 2 all of the data is there.
I have tried adding up to 1.5ms of delay after blocking call returns, the more delay there the more data shows up, with 1.5ms of delay all but the first packet shows. When re reading through the buffer afterwards the correct first packet is there.
I should mention that the test data I am using is essentially just a counter with a header attached to it so very easy to see that none of the data is out of order.
I have attempted to  msync(m_bufs[rd_idx], PKT_MAX_SIZE, MS_SYNC); before writing each index to file but was unable to get that call to work properly (and not 100% it is the correct use for that function). Calling it directly on the pointer caused an error, something to do with page alignment whoch caused me to switch to
void *aligned_addr = (void *)((uintptr_t)m_bufs[rd_idx] & ~(page_size - 1));
   
   
    if(msync(aligned_addr, PKT_MAX_SIZE, MS_SYNC) == -1)
    {
        printf("errno: %d", errno);
        perror("msync");
    }

Which no longer throws an error but seemed to have no effect on the problem
I have also tried to add the MAP_SYNC flag to my mmap call which seems like a better solution but that always seems to fail. Presumably due to not having the dax enabled on the file system based on this stack overflow page I found. Having trouble figuring out how to enable dax on my current board setup/arch
Is it normal to have that much latency between mmap'd buffers? I used the same approach for mapping the buffers, blocking calls etc but with DMA instead and did not have this latency issue on the same board configuration.
Is there something glaringly obvious that I am missing here?
EDIT:
Buffer allocation:
for (i = 0; i < PCI_PKT_BUFS; i++)
    {
        lowspeed_dat.rx_pkt_queue.buffers[i] = kzalloc(PCI_PKT_MAX_SIZE, GFP_KERNEL);
}

Basic "read" strategy
 while (running)
    {
        if (false == gotIndex)
        {
            if (ioctl(fd, PCI_GET_RD_IDX, &index) != -1)
            {
                printf("Got Chan index: %d\n", index);
                gotIndex = true;
            } else{
                printf("Failed to get index\n");
            }
        }

        if (gotIndex == true)
        {
            if (ioctl(fd, PCI_READ_CHAN_A, &val) != -1)
            {
                // printf("Read IOCTL succesful val = %d\n", val);
                gotIndex = true;
            }


            if (val > 0)
            {
                gotIndex = false;
                // usleep(1500);
                writeLowSpeedDataToFile(index, file);
            } else 
            {
                printf("Read Chan A failed\n");
                running = false;
            }
        }
    }
}

Kernel side of the ioctl:
long readChanA(unsigned long arg, void *dev_id)
{
    u32 size;
    int ret = -1;   // return value
    int result = 0; // result of the wait
    unsigned int old_idx = 0;                        // current slot in the rx queue
    unsigned int new_idx = 0;                        // next slot in the tx queue
    pci_ls_pkt_queue *queue = &lowspeed_dat.rx_pkt_queue[CHANNEL_A];

    printk("Chan A: wr_idx = %d rd_idx = %d\n", queue->wr_idx, queue->rd_idx);
    
    old_idx = queue->rd_idx;
    new_idx = (queue->rd_idx + 1) % PCI_PKT_BUFS;
    printk("1\n");


    // wait until a packet is available or we timeout while waiting
    result = wait_event_interruptible_timeout(chan_a_wait_queue,
                                            ((queue->wr_idx + 1) % PCI_PKT_BUFS) != new_idx, HZ);

    printk("4\n");
    
    // if a packet is available, return a passing value
    if (result > 0)
    {
        ret = 0;
        printk("Chan A: wr_idx = %d new rd_idx = %d\n", queue->wr_idx, new_idx);
        queue->rd_idx = new_idx;
        printk("5\n");
        return result;
    }
    else
    {
        printk("Timed out \n");
        return -1;
    }
    return ret;
}

Example of how buffer is written to:
uint32_t *buf = (uint32_t*)queue->buffers[queue->wr_idx];

*buf = readReg(queue->fifo);
buf++;

//once buffer has full packet
queue->wr_idx = (queue->wr_idx + 1) % PCI_PKT_BUFS;
buf = (uint32_t*)queue->buffers[queue->wr_idx];

wake_up_interruptible(&chan_a_wait_queue);


How is the memory for the buffers allocated? How are the buffers written to? How and when is the user space side alerted?

Memory for the each buffer is allocated via an ioctl after the user space opens the driver, using kzalloc:
The buffers are written to by doing sequential 32 bit reads from a register directly into the buffer. Number of reads dependent on the size of the packet.
The user space is essentially doing an ioctl into the driver to act as a blocking call (essentially acting as a read() call but I have multiple channels) Which then waits on a wait queue. The wait queue is awoken after the last packet has been read into the buffer, which returns the ioctl. Will add code snippets to original

Are the buffers page-aligned? Try replacing kzalloc(PCI_PKT_MAX_SIZE, GFP_KERNEL); with alloc_pages_exact(PCI_PKT_MAX_SIZE, GFP_KERNEL | __GFP_ZERO); and freeing them with free_pages_exact(buf, PCI_PKT_MAX_SIZE);.

Just gave it a shot and it did not seem to make any difference using alloc_pages_exact over kzalloc

kzalloc will give you page-aligned buffers anyway when the size is above a certain threshold, but the page allocators are more explicit about the alignment. The page allocators are wasteful if PCI_PKT_MAX_SIZE is much smaller than PAGE_SIZE, but then you'd need to rethink your buffer strategy in that case, by for example mmaping one large buffer split into PKT_MAX_SIZE-size chunks.

In this case PCI_PKT_MAX_SIZE is much larger than PAGE_SIZE ( PCI_PKT_MAX_SIZE being 64k and  PAGE_SIZE being 4k according to get conf) though the data I am testing with currently is very small ~140 bytes at the largest. What advantage does having 1 larger buffer (would be about 2MB) vs 32 smaller buffers (64k each) ?
